# How can create userManager directly with 'id_token', 'access_token', expiry etc.?

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

In my angular app I have used oidc-client.js library. previously, everything was fine because I have configured all minimal required fields  as below

```
      "resourceUrl": "//xxxxx.abc.net",
      "clientId": "cdgdsg335",
      "authority": "//xyz.com/A1",
      "response_type": "id_token token",
      "response_mode": "query",
      "scope": "openid email profile",
      "automaticSilentRenew": false,
      "silent_renew_url": "/silent-renew.html",
      "redirect_url": "/auth-callback",
      "post_logout_redirect_url": "/login"
```

But now, Instead of redirecting to authentication site using authority url and getting tokens through redirection call, the back-end has provided the direct api (/token) to fetch id_token, access_token and refresh token.So, How can I configure user using userManager without using signinRedirect() and signinRedirectCallback().
Please help me with this?

I tried tweaking userManager.settings but no luck

Answer (score 0):

The oidc-client library is for Javascript only flows, and you will need to use a back end for front end approach to do things as you suggest.

Here is some [sample code for an SPA](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/oauth/oauthClient.ts) that uses only API calls - as you can see the code is simplified - there is a [related article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-handler-spa-example/) also.

Doing SPA security via an API is a more secure solution though a little tricky - but the above resources will show how.